# Javascript async value does not get passed to the next function call

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-jsonschema-forms

I have this onChange method with its related function calls below for React-Jsonschema-Form. The problem I am facing is, newFormData when get passed to computeValueByFormula does not pass the async value.

```
onChange = ({ schema, formData }) => {
    const { properties } = schema

    this.updateTotalCell(properties)

    lookUpValue(properties, formData).then(newFormData => {
        const newFormData2 = computeValueByFormula(properties, newFormData)
        this.setState({ formData: newFormData2 })
    })
}

// recursive function to do math calculation on string formula input
// use case: mathCalculation("1 * 2 + 4 / 2 - 6")
export function mathCalculation (formula) {
  const plusOperator = '+'
  const minusOperator = '-'
  const multiplyOperator = '*'
  const divideOperator = '/'

  if (formula.indexOf(plusOperator) > 0) {
    const operands = formula.split(plusOperator)
    let total = 0

    operands.forEach(operand => {
      total = total + mathCalculation(operand)
    })

    return total
  }

  else if (formula.indexOf(minusOperator) > 0) {
    const operands = formula.split(minusOperator)
    let total = 0

    operands.forEach((operand, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        total = mathCalculation(operand)
      } 
      else {
        total = total - mathCalculation(operand)
      }
    })

    return total
  }

  else if (formula.indexOf(multiplyOperator) > 0) {
    const operands = formula.split(multiplyOperator)
    let total = 1

    operands.forEach(operand => {
      total = total * mathCalculation(operand)
    })

    return total
  }

  else if (formula.indexOf(divideOperator) > 0) {
    const operands = formula.split(divideOperator)
    let total = 1

    operands.forEach((operand, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        total = mathCalculation(operand)
      }
      else {
        total = total / mathCalculation(operand)
      }
    })

    return total
  }

  return Number(formula)
}

// compute field value based on value of other fields
export function computeValueByFormula (properties, formData) {
  let newFormData = {...formData}

  Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
    if (properties[key].formula) {
      const formula = properties[key].formula

      let operands = formula.replace(/\+|-|\*|\//g, ' ').split(' ')
      operands = operands.map(operand => formData[operand])

      if (properties[key].type === 'number') {
        const operators = formula.replace(/\w/g, '').split('')
        const updatedFormula = operands.map(operand => operators.length > 0 ? operand + operators.shift() : operand).join('')
        newFormData[key] = mathCalculation(updatedFormula)
      }
      else if (properties[key].type === 'string'){
        newFormData[key] = operands.join(' ')
      }
    }
    else if (properties[key].type === 'array') {
      if (formData[key] !== undefined) {
        newFormData[key].forEach((item, childKey) => {
          newFormData[key][childKey] = computeValueByFormula(properties[key].items.properties, formData[key][childKey])
        })
      }
    }
  })

  return newFormData
}

// lookup value based on value of other field
export function lookUpValue (properties, formData, parentFieldName, parentFormData) {
  let newFormData = {...formData}

  Object.keys(properties).forEach(async (key) => {
    if (properties[key].lookup) {
      const { collection, field, parameterField } = properties[key].lookup

      if (parentFormData !== undefined) { // pattern is in array field item
        if (parameterField.indexOf(':') > 0) { // parsing array field item
          const arrayRef = parameterField.split(':')
          const arrayField = arrayRef[0]
          const itemField = arrayRef[1]

          if (arrayField === parentFieldName) {
            const lookupValue = formData[itemField]
            newFormData[key] = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/record-lookup?collection_id=${collection}&lookup_field=${itemField}&lookup_value=${lookupValue}&lookup_target_field=${field}`)
              .then(res => res.data.data)
          }
        } else {
          const lookupValue = parentFormData[parameterField]
          newFormData[key] = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/record-lookup?collection_id=${collection}&lookup_field=${parameterField}&lookup_value=${lookupValue}&lookup_target_field=${field}`)
            .then(res => res.data.data)
        }
      } else {
        const lookupValue = formData[parameterField]
        newFormData[key] = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/record-lookup?collection_id=${collection}&lookup_field=${parameterField}&lookup_value=${lookupValue}&lookup_target_field=${field}`)
          .then(res => res.data.data)
      }
    }
    else if (properties[key].type === 'array') {
      if (formData[key] !== undefined) {
        newFormData[key].forEach(async (item, childKey) => {
            newFormData[key][childKey] = await lookUpValue(properties[key].items.properties, formData[key][childKey], key, formData).then(data => data)
        })
      }
    }
  })

  return Promise.resolve(newFormData)
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to look up a value based on user's input on the form. Let's say I have currency table on the database, whenever a user change a dropdown select of currency name, another field which supposed to hold the currency rate will do server call to fetch related currency data from database.

This field will have a lookup field on the schema. The same as field which has math calculation on it, will have formula field on the schema.

Somehow after the server call, it will update the formData on the other places, but formData that's passed to computeValueByFormula is not updated. Even if I pass it directly without the spread operator.

This give me a blank field on the form while on the formData I have the value.

Note: The recursive form of the functions needed to evaluate the array field items.

Comment: `lookUpValue` is not declared as an `async` function. No `try..catch` blocks or error handlers within `.catch()` appear at the code at the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving the `lookUpValue` function right away with `newFormData` by returning `Promise.resolve(newFormData)`. This will not wait for any asynchronous callbacks being done inside your `Object.keys(...).forEach(...)`-loop. As `lookUpValue` has some asynchronous calculations, it should wait for them to finish.

If `lookUpValue` was marked as `async`, you could leave out the `async` keyword in the `Object.keys(...).forEach(key => {...})` loop and it should wait for the `await` calls.

There is one caveat though: It will run the for each `await` calls **sequentially**, so it might take some time. It might be a better idea in this case to create multiple Promises and wait for them in parallel through `Promise.all`.

Using the parallel approach might yield performance boosts, but it may also introduce bugs due to race conditions. Especially since you are going through your state recursively there might be additional complexity involved.

Comment: it doesn't seem to solve the issue. If I don't put async in array.forEach it will trigger another error stating that await should be used only within async function. I really need for the function to stop executing until the async value is resolved. Not really care of the performance issue currently.

Comment: You need to mark `lookUpValue` with `async` as well: `async function lookUpValue(properties, formData, parentFieldName, parentFormData) {` for that to work

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean in the `Object.keys` - you could use `reduce` instead of `forEach` to return a promise and wait for it: `await Object.keys(...).reduce(async (lastPromise, key) => { await lastPromise; ... }, Promise.resolve())`

Comment: I tried using array.reduce, it gives the same behavior. When I debug step by step, the `this.setState` is called before the async value resolved. I can't make the execution sequentially until the async value resolved.

Comment: It should not resolve, if you properly await each step... a basic example would be: `[1, 2, 3].reduce(async (lastPromise, n) => { const sum = await lastPromise; await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); return sum + n }, Promise.resolve(0)).then(sum => console.log(sum));` - maybe you could provide a codesandbox, jsfiddle or make some test code?